# Move git repo from github to linux server

Tags: git, github

I want to transfer a git repo from github to a linux server.
I want to transfer the full repo to have it installed on the linux server with the same history/branches/etc than the ones it has currently on github.
I want it to be a bare repo.
To achieve the former, is it ok to do the following?:

1- go to the desired path in the linux server

2- git clone --bare https://github.com/username/repo

3- go to each of the local working copies of the developers machines and update the origin to the new server.

Comment: Sure, why wouldn't it be?

Comment: I got confused because when i looked for this expecting to be something simple I found complete tutorials talking about executing a bunch of commands.

Comment: Lots of people overcomplicate stuff.

Comment: ok, just wanted to be sure thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. That is exactly how you would go about doing that. Make sure to create local versions of all the branches after you clone in the bare repo (step 2.5).

Answer (score 0):

The `etc` part is your question is problematic.

There are at least 2 things that you don't get when clone a repository.

1. Reflogs.  These may or may not be important to you
2. Hooks.  If present, these probably are important to you

If you need either of these preserved you'll have to transfer them manually.  Other than that `git clone --bare` and then updating the client remotes is correct.  You would probably also want to change your githut repository to be read only, and perhaps to present instructions on the new location on a failed push.